# WPF 3D - How do I update mesh positions in realtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

How do I update the position of a 3D object in WPF (a ModelVisual3D for example) at a really high rate (say 60+ frames per second) using real data?

I have been combing this site, Petzold's book, and google for information for a while and am unable to find a solid answer.  Most examples assume you are only going to update position data once per second and will use an animation to smooth the transition.  I am representing the position of a real-life object (your hand for example) so I need to update it's position as fast as the framework is able, and since I don't know where the next location will be and I don't want too much lag I can't use animations.

1. In Petzold's book, [and this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748838(v=vs.110).aspx) he mentions in passing that you should use `CompositionTarget.Rendering` if you are updating positions at near-refresh speeds, but his book was written in 2008.  Is that still the accepted answer?  I'm used to regular WPF and all of the great DataBinding MVVM patterns, is that too slow for real-time updates?
2. When updating positions, there are Transforms, and then there are the actual points that the mesh is composed of.  Is it faster to use a transform to move the object or update it's points? (taking into account [rules for optimizing 3D collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timothyc/archive/2006/08/31/734308.aspx)

Comment: Are you using MeshGeometry3D classes to represent your mesh? You better update your Transform rather than looping through mesh points